# How can we find the voltage gain of a BJT circuit if the Vin and Vout are on different transistors?

Tags: voltage, transistors, bjt, npn, gain

I am trying to find the voltage gain of the circuit below. I drew the small-signal model for it (shown below). I know the formula for finding the voltage gain of a common-emitter BJT with and without degeneration (also shown below). The problem is, the formula applies when Vout and Vin are connected to the same transistor, but the circuit I'm dealing with has the Vout on the transistor Q2 and Vin on the transistor Q1. According to the small-signal model, I've found the voltage gain as `gm1*(RC//Rπ2)`. I've used the formula for the common-emitter BJT without degeneration, but Q2 has degeneration and the resistor for Vout is RD. I'm not sure if the voltage gain I found is correct. I would really appreciate it if I can get an answer on what I should do to find the voltage gain for all BJT circuits in general. Thank you in advance.

### Circuit

[image]

### Small-Signal Model

[image]

### Formulas for Finding the Voltage Gain of Common-Emitter BJTs

[image]

Comment: Hint: The top transistor isn't in a common-emitter configuration.

Comment: Is it in common-base configuration, since there is no voltage applied to its base?

Comment: Yes, and together these make up a common circuit called the cascode, which may be a useful search term. Notice what the configuration means for the collector voltage of the input transistor, and what that means for the configuration's bandwidth. Q2's base really should be tied somewhere other than Vcc, though. (of course, Q1 should be biased to linearize the gain and protect it from overvoltage, or Vin should be a current, so this is clearly meant to be a didactic circuit more than a practical one)

Comment: I've looked at our course book and found nothing similar to this circuit (Vout and Vin on different transistors). I have no idea what to do to solve a question like this. I also thought the voltage gain as gm1*(RC//Rπ2//RD). Could you tell me what I should do to find the voltage gain (if I am wrong that is) because our course book has different solutions for cascade circuits.

Comment: Cascode, not cascade. It's not too common nowadays outside of RF circuitry and other things that need the high bandwidth it provides, but it used to be much more common back when analog circuit design was more prevalent.

Comment: Hmm, the voltage gain of a Q1 stage is \$\frac{r_{e2}||R_C}{r_{e1}} * \frac{\beta_1}{\beta_1 +1}\$ and the Q2 stage gain is \$ \frac{R_D}{r_{e2}}* \frac{\beta_2}{\beta_2 +1}\$  do you fallow?

Comment: or Q1 gain is \$g_{m1} \times (R_C||r_{\pi2}||\frac{1}{g_{m2}}) = g_{m1} \times (R_C||\frac{r_{\pi2}}{\beta_2 +1})\$ and Q2 gain is \$g_{m2}R_D\$

Comment: That schematic looks naïve and hence faulty to me.

Comment: @G36 I would really appreciate if you could guide me through the steps for finding the gains. Even better, I would be really happy if you could recommend a video or any other sources that would help me because I can't seem to find any good sources for cascode amplifiers. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you able to find the voltage gain of this amplifier https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqHz7.png

Comment: I found it as gm1*(RC//rπ2) but I don't know how to get the (1/gm2).

Comment: @G36 Could you share your solution by answering this post because I genuinely can not find the answer gm1×(RC||rπ2||1gm2). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your theoretical circuit can be seen as a two-stage amplifier.

The first stage is nothing more than a common-emitter amplifier.
And the second stage is a common-base amplifier.

The first stage gain can be found using this equivalent circuit:

[image]

As you can see the input impedance of a common-base amplifier is \$r_{\pi 2}|| \frac{1}{g_{m2}}\$

[output resistance of BJT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/564786/output-resistance-of-bjt/564854#564854)

Therefore, we can solve for a voltage gain:

$$V_{C1} = - I_{C1}(r_{\pi 2}|| \frac{1}{g_{m2}}||R_C) = - V_{in}*g_{m1}*(r_{\pi 2}|| \frac{1}{g_{m2}}||R_C)$$

Thus,

$$\frac{V_{C1}}{V_{in}} = -g_{m1}*(r_{\pi 2}|| \frac{1}{g_{m2}}||R_C)$$

Now the common-base stage gain can be found using this equivalent circuit:

[image]

As you can see \$V_{C1} = V_{in}\$ thus:

$$V_{OUT} = -I_{C2}*R_D = - (-V_{in})*g_{m2}*R_D = V_{in}*g_{m2}*R_D$$

And finally we have:

$$\frac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} = g_{m2}R_D$$

And this is the end of this simple analysis.

Comment: I am sorry, I know I am taking your time with this. On our midterm exam we got this question and I don't think I got the right answer. So, I am trying to understand the concept well so if we get a similar question on our final I won't have any problems solving it. Now, what I don't understand is you said "... common-base amplifier is rπ2||(1/gm2)" What about RC, shouldn't that be in parallel with the output resistance as well making the output resistance RC||rπ2||(1/gm2)? Furthermore, how did we find (1/gm2)? Also, thank you for your time, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Also another question, why was RC removed in the second figure (common-base equivalent circuit)? Shouldn't it be common-base with degeneration?

Comment: @Kalamakra What is the input impedance of a common-base amplifer? Do you know how to find it?

Comment: It is 1/gm but in our case, shouldn't the input impedance for the common-base be RC||1/gm?

Comment: Well, the exact solution shows that \$ \Large r_{in} = \frac{1}{g_m} || r_\pi = \frac{1}{ g_m + \frac{1}{r_{\pi}}} = \frac{r_{\pi}}{g_mr_{\pi} +1}  = \frac{r_{\pi}}{\beta +1} = r_e\$

Comment: @Kalamakra But RC is not a part of a CB amplifier.  RC is load resistance for CE amplifier.  CB r_in is also a load for CE stage. Do you see it? And do you understand why we have 1/gm2 on the equivalent circuit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126672/discussion-between-kalamakra-and-g36).

Comment: Would our gain be [−gm1∗(rπ2||(1/gm2)||RC)] if gm1=gm2?

Comment: I would say -gm*Rd

Comment: I tried solving it but I still can't transform RD into 1/gm2 in the circuit https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqHz7.png Resistor on the top left corner.

Comment: But can you find the Rin for this circuit? https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEjvL.png

Comment: Also, why do you think that in the schematic RD is transform into 1/gm2?

Comment: Is it because CE stage's collector is connected to CB stage's emittor, and since Vin of CB stage was rpi2||1/gm2 thats why 1/gm2 is there?

Comment: Exactly, this is the case.

Comment: Thank you so much.